# PHP Insert Text and Image to Database and Retrieve it

Tags: php, html

AddStdRecord.php
this is the AddStd record form that i need to get to the addoutput.php the insert it on database

### Add Student Information

```
<form action="AddOutput.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
style="border:1px solid #ccc">
<div class="container">

<b>Select file to upload:</b></br></br>
<input type="file" name="UploadImage" id="UploadImage">
</br></br>
<label><b>Student ID</b></label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Student Number" name="txtID" required>

<label><b>Last Name</b></label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Last Name" name="txtLname" required>
<label><b>First name</b></label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter First Name" name="txtFname" required>

<label><b>Middle Name</b></label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Middle Name" name="txtMname" required>

<label><b>Birthday</b></label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Birthday" name="txtBday" required>

<label><b>Gender</b></label><br><br>
<input type="radio" name="rbgender" value="Male" checked="checked"><b>Male</b>
<input type="radio" name="rbgender" value="Female"><b>Female </b><br><br>

<label><b>Address</b></label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Address" name="txtAdd" required>

<label><b>Father's Name</b></label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Father's Name" name="txtfather" required>

<label><b>Mother's Name</b></label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Mother's Name" name="txtmother" required>

<label><b>Contact</b></label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Contact Number" name="txtcontact" required>

<label><b>Previous School</b></label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Previous School Attended" name="txtPrev" required>

<div class="clearfix">
<button type="button" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="signupbtn">Add Student</button>


</form></br></br>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

AddOutput.php
code to input to the database, whats wrong with this?

```
include_once('connection.php');


$StdID = $_REQUEST['txtID'];
$Lname = $_REQUEST['txtLname'];
$Fname = $_REQUEST['txtFname'];
$Mname = $_REQUEST['txtMname'];
$Bday = $_REQUEST['txtBday'];
$Gender = $_REQUEST['rbgender'];
$Add = $_REQUEST['txtAdd'];
$Father = $_REQUEST['txtfather'];
$Mother = $_REQUEST['txtmother'];
$Contact = $_REQUEST['txtcontact'];
$PrevSch = $_REQUEST['txtPrev'];



$target_dir = "StdImg/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["UploadImage"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
 } else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
  }
 }
// Check if file already exists
 if (file_exists($target_file)) {
echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["UploadImage"]["size"] > 500000) {
echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
}


$sql = "INSERT INTO tblstdpro VALUES ('".$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."\\StdImg\\".$fileToUpload."', '$StdID', '$Lname', '$Fname', '$Mname', '$Bday', '$Gender', '$Add', '$Father', '$Mother', '$Contact', '$PrevSch')";

   if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
header("Location: AddStdRec.php?");
  } else {
   echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
 }

$conn->close();
?>
```

is there any mistake that i input? it goes to the main folder but doesn't go to the database, i have been searching for days about this function, but cant seem to find one, please comment my mistakes thank you in advance

Comment: Are you getting an error after the insert attempt?

Comment: no, it doesnt go to the database but it goes to the pathfile

Comment: I understand that it's not "going to the DB", but are you getting an error? Based on your code, if the insert fails (presumably), then you should see an error output, or does the header redirect actually happen?  Also, I don't see anywhere how `$fileToUpload` is set?

Comment: (continued) ... (you might already know this, but just in case) ... since you don't specify columns with the insert (which is ok), however, the values that are being inserted must match the table's column order.

Comment: there is no error when clicking but it doest go to database can you help me fix this code?

Comment: it is in order, i just dont know why it doesnt go in the database anyway , the filetoupload is = UploadImage, i forgot to edit it , when i check the database all the information is there except the image path file

Comment: Why would that not instead be `$target_file`?  Anyway, at least edit your question for that area. You might try to echo the same path (before the insert) to see how it appears. You might have to (temporarily) comment-out the header line or you might not see the message when the page redirects.

Comment: how would you do that?? please help me

Comment: Do what ... the comment out, or the echo, or the post edit?

Comment: got it thank you so much, how can i thank by liking or something?

Comment: What did you discover?

Comment: i tried the targetfile and it works after how many hours , you gave me the idea thanks man